# Calling javascript from button vs link

Tags: javascript, html, button

Is anyone able to tell me please why clicking on this in an HTML page

```
<a onclick="addRow(); return false;" href="#">Add Row</a>
```

causes addRow to be called, but this

```
<input id="addRow" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow(); return false;" />
```

does not?

(I want a button which calls addRow.)

Comment: post the addRow() function

Comment: Hmm, easier said than done. If I add it I can't submit the edit - StackOverflow complains that my post is mostly code and I need to add some more details. Not really sure what it wants.  It there a specific thing you are looking for? The function DOES work when called in the first way.

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/s9nkw4cj/). Although I'm not sure that an `href` on an `<input>` is valid, I would remove it. Also is that input item in a `form`?

Comment: Sorry, the href was a hangover from something I was trying. Removed.  Yes the input item is in a form.

Comment: something to do with id? which input has but <a> doesn't? between any errors in the console?

Comment: It was indeed the "id" - thanks. I don't understand why, TBH - but here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/sysLrsby/

Comment: @MarkSmith It's because they have the same name, it confuses JavaScript since it could try to interpret `addRow`as a global variable for the element with that id other than a function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other that adding the JavaScript as a `onclick` inline with the HTML add it as an event listener in JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("addRow").addEventListener("click", addRow, false);
```

The problem is coming from the id's name `addRow` vs the function call `addRow()`, since some browsers will interpret id's as global variable names. This causes an issue with the function call inline HTML. Simply changing the id or function name also works, for example changing the id to `id="add_row"`:

```
<input id="add_row" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add listener on button like this, here is the demo code...

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>

var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
   addRow();
});
function addRow() {
   alert("working");
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bk0ddwur/)